# SQL on CSV using HSQLDB JDBC Driver

Tags: java, csv, hsqldb

I have a pregenerated CSV file on which I need to run SQL queries. I've been looking at different open source solutions (e.g. CsvJdbc, xlSQL etc) but haven't really found anything satisfactory.

CsvJdbc couldn't recognize ORDER BY, GROUP BY etc 
xlSQL only runs on XLS files, not CSV (or I haven't been able to get it to run with CSV. Anybody know how?). Plus it's not in development or supported anymore.

I read somewhere that HSQLDB supports querying on CSV files, but I haven't been able to work it correctly. Here's what I've done till now:

If I create a CSV File using HSQLDB, then it's able to execute queries successfully. Here's the code for that:

```
String driver = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String protocol = "jdbc:hsqldb:file";
final String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/C:/Users/varun.achar/Documents";

final StringBuilder createTable = new StringBuilder();
createTable.append("CREATE TEXT TABLE currency (");
createTable.append("id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR)");
final StringBuilder linkTable = new StringBuilder();
linkTable.append("SET TABLE currency SOURCE ");
linkTable.append("\"/currencies.csv");
linkTable.append(";ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true\"");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "");
Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
stm.execute(createTable.toString());
stm.execute(linkTable.toString());
ResultSet resultSet = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CURRENCY");
if (resultSet != null) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("CURRENCY = " + resultSet.getString(2));
    }
}
conn.close();
```

But the same thing doesn't work when I delete the file and run it again! I get the error

> Table already exists: CURRENCY in statement [CREATE TEXT TABLE currency]

Also, If I have a pre-existing csv file ( the formatting is correct since I was able to run a simple select statement using CsvJDBC) then I get the error

> Table not found: RMS in statement [SET TABLE rms]

Code for this

```
final StringBuilder linkTable = new StringBuilder();
linkTable.append("SET TABLE rms SOURCE ");
linkTable.append("\"C:/myreports/temp/user/1316083232009/rms.csv");
linkTable.append(";ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true\"");
Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
System.out.println("Driver was successfully loaded.");
String protocol = "jdbc:hsqldb:file";
String database = "C:\\myreports\\temp\\user\\1316083232009\\rms.csv";
String url = protocol + ":" + database;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
stm = con.createStatement();
stm.execute(linkTable.toString());
resultSet = stm.executeQuery(testSQLStatement());
if (resultSet != null) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("FULL NAME = "+ resultSet.getString("usr_FULL_NAME"));
    }
}
```

Can somebody throw some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single HSQLDB database can have many tables, including several TEXT tables. It seems you think there must be one database per each text table, which is not the case.

The database path is not a directory. It is not a CSV file either. In your first example you should specify a database name such as this:

```
final String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/C:/Users/varun.achar/Documents/mydb";
```

The same in your second example.

The database consists of a few files beginning with the names you sepcified. In this example, you will have `mydb.properties`, `mydb.script`, etc.

The `CREATE TEXT TABLE ...` statement creates the metadata for the table. This table metadata is persisted in the database.

The first example will then work. If you delete the CSV file, then open the database, the 'CREATE TEXT TABLE' statement is still stored in the database, therefore it complains when you attempt to create the same table again.

If you have a preexisting CVS file, you still need to start with `CREATE TEXT TABLE ...`, then link it with the CVS using the SET TABLE statement, the same way as the first example.

Comment: Thanks.. I'd figured it out too.. :D

Comment: Though I wanted to ask, does hsqldb read the entire file into memory before applying the where clauses etc or does it have a mechanism through which it performs these operations on the file directly?

Comment: It reads the entire file once to create the indexes. It then reads selective rows. The primary key column has an auto index. If the WHERE clause is on a different column, you need to create an index on the column. It is faster to create the indexes before the SET TABLE statement.

Comment: My CSV contains `time` in `epoch` format. How can I get it to recognize that time is in that format when running a `select` statement? My `DDL` script reads like so: `CREATE TEXT TABLE ABC ( START_DATE TIMESTAMP)`. When i'm running a select statement on this I get, `IllegalArgumentException`. How do I get it to recognize the `timestamp` format?

Comment: For example WHERE START_DATE > TIEMSTAMP '2011-11-05 12:00:00'

Comment: My START_DATE contains this value `1269541800000`. How do I run a `select` so that I get a `date`? Will I need to use a `date` function to convert it into `date`? Is my `DDL` correct for such data?

Comment: SET TABLE ABC SOURCE .. will not succeed if the CSV data is not formatted like 2011-11-05 12:00:00. You need to define the column as BIGINT, then run queries such as `WHERE START_DATE > (TIMESTAMP '2011-11-05 12:00:00' - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00') SECOND / 1000` to use the index. To display the millis as timestamp, add the value: `TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + CAST(START_DATE / 1000 AS INTERVAL SECOND)`